# I have an issue when pushing to a network drive using Git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have what seems to be a fairly rare circumstance, so I'll try and be specific:

I'm on Windows.
I have permissions for the network directories concerned.
I'm using a very recent version of Git (2.24.0).

I am creating a remote repo on a network drive (can't use cloud based ones, e.g. Bit Bucket / GitHub).
I'm adding LFS since there will be many large files involved. The LFS repo directory is at the same level as the remote repo, e.g.

```
//$network/a/b/c/MyRepo
//$network/a/b/c/MyRepoLFS
```

I already have a .gitattributes file, which is why I'm not doing git track commands below.
The steps I'm using to set everything up are:

1. Create the above directories on the network.
2. From `//$network/a/b/c/MyRepo`, start Bash and type `"git init myrepo.git"`.
3. On the PC, I have a Unity project made for testing. In the root directory of the project, I type:

   ```
   git init

   git lfs install

   git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url //$network/a/b/c/MyRepo/MyRepoLFS

   git remote add origin //$network/a/b/c/MyRepo/myrepo.git

   git add .lfsconfig      ==> Not sure if this is needed before the "git add --all" but won't hurt?

   git add -–all

   git commit –m “Initial commit”

   git push origin master
   ```

It's here that I get the error:

**error: failed to push some refs to '//$network/a/b/c/MyRepo/myrepo.git'**

and I can't work out what I've done wrong. It seems to load the LFS files (`"EOFoading LFS objects: 100% (64/64), 43 MB | 0 B/s"`) but can't add the refs?

I've tried switching the order of some of these things but I suspect it's something more fundamental that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you need git init --bare in the remote?

Comment: @Christoph: I think that is exactly the problem. A `git init x` will create a new repository with `x` being the working directory, and `x/.git` being the repository folder. The `--bare` flag makes `x` the repository folder with no working directory. Git will reject push's to repositories with working directories when it detects that files need merging (even if Git could auto merge the files).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there isn't an LFS server running, which I thought there was. Which explains why nothing could be pushed.

Comment: That had nothing to do with lfs. See your Won comment above...

Comment: I can't retry at the moment but I tried with --bare before (should have mentioned that in the original posy) and it told me that it wasn't a repositpry when I tried to push. Apologies, I've always been a basic git user, not used to setting these things up